# parsimonious definition of a zig-zag function between two bounds

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

Suppose I have some strictly increasing function $f:[0,b]\to[0,b]$ with $0<b<1$,   $f(x)<x$ and $f'(b)=\frac{1-f(b)}{1-b}$ (i.e. tangent to the secant line to $(1,1)$). Now imagine a 'tunnel' of width $\epsilon$ around it. I want to define a zig zag function of the following shape:

Starting at $(f(b),b)$, go down always on a secant either to $(1,1)$ or $(0,0)$, changing slopes every time you hit the boundary.

A picture can explain it better than words:
[image: zig-zag line defined in the text]

Is there a parsimonious way to formally define this line?

**Edit:** For the zig-zag function to be well-defined, assume also that the function $f$ needs to have increasing tangent slope to $(1,1)$ and to $(0,0)$, i.e. $$\frac{f(x)}{x}\text{ and }\frac{1-f(x)}{1-x}$$ are both increasing in $x$.

Comment: Just a curiosity, when the red line changes slope, is it reflected off the tangent of the grey line? I.e. does it make equal angles to the grey line's tangent?

Comment: @ColmBhandal Not in general, no. For instance, in the picture, the lowest corner kind of illustrates that.

Comment: Ah. Are the red lines in the pic supposed to be parallel?

Comment: @ColmBhandal. No, they aren't They always point to either the (1,1) point (upper right corner) or (0,0) (lower left corner) alternatively.

Comment: Yes I fully understand the problem now. Unfortunately I have no ideas at the moment. Good problem.